# Is there a way to show discord members in a server in html

Tags: javascript, html, discord, discord.js

I have a problem / question. I want to have a list of all users in a discord server but I don't know how to display the list in html. There is my code :

```
const data = new FormData();

            data.append('client_id', '573300679112785920');
            data.append('client_secret', 'secret');
            data.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
            data.append('redirect_uri', 'http://localhost:5665/?token=123456');
            data.append('scope', 'identify guilds');
            data.append('code', "secret");

            fetch('https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
            })
            .then(info => fetch('https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/506162141888380938/members?limit=20', {
                headers: {
                    authorization: `Bot [botToken]`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },  
            }))
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(console.log);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you specify how the response look like

Comment: This is what I get ```{
    user: {
      id: '159985870458322944',
      username: 'MEE6',
      avatar: 'b50adff099924dd5e6b72d13f77eb9d7',
      discriminator: '4876',
      public_flags: 65536,
      bot: true
    },
    roles: [ '723199188191543397' ],
    nick: null,
    premium_since: null,
    mute: false,
    deaf: false,
    joined_at: '2020-06-18T15:35:22.878000+00:00'
  },
 
]```
( I don't have enough characters to put all the users)

Comment: please update your code and post the response there in a legible way